# How to extract year from a column with mixed formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have column in my dataset that looks like has the date in many different formats. Sometimes it only has the year and month, and other times only the year:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1 January 1980 |
| Oct-74 |
| Oct-17 |
| 1980.0 |
| -200 |
| -50 |
| 8 |

I want to extract only the year from this column. For dates which are in the format "mmm-yy", I want to assume they are between 1921 and 2020. So my above column should look like this:

| Year |
| --- |
| 1980 |
| 1974 |
| 2017 |
| 1980 |
| -200 |
| -50 |
| 8 |

How can I do this in Python? Any help would be appreciated.

```
#here is the code for the first dataframe
data = {'date': ['1 January 1980','Oct-74', 'Oct-17', '1980.0', '-200.0', '-50']}  
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {'date': ['1 January 1980','Oct-74', 'Oct-17', '1980.0', '-200.0', '-50', '8']}  
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
temp = df['date'].str.replace('[a-zA-Z]{3}-', '+').str.extract('([-+\.\d]{1,}$)')
m1 = temp[0].str.contains('\+')
temp[0] = temp[0].astype(float)
temp[0] = temp[0].where(~((m1)&(temp[0]>=21)), 1900+temp[0])
temp[0] = temp[0].where(~((m1)&(temp[0]<21)), 2000+temp[0])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The only issue I found with this is that it doesn't work for instances such as if date is "8" (in which instance I want the year to be 8, whereas this returns NaN). From my understanding, the regex in the replace command filters for date types of "OCT-74". 

Does that mean that the regex in the extract command needs to be tweaked? And the subsequent lines so we don't add 2000 or 1900 for such rows?

Comment: I've also edited my original question to add the example where date and 
year can be 8, as I realised it adds complexity to the solution

Comment: Check the answer now.